# RecyclerView is mess for lower than a Second

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have a working RecyclerView...In onResume I startListening()...
The Problem is, that the FirebaseRecyclerView is mess when I resume the Activity for lower than one second. So I start the App and see the unsorted RecyclerView and after lower than a Second it gets sorted correctly.
Anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Here is a short video how it looks like:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1c12tnbuuup2vrj/fp_4K.mp4?dl=0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess, we cant see your code unless you put them here.

Comment: The "mess" likely happens because the data hasn't come back from the Firebase servers yet. The solution is to either ensure that your layouts looks fine even when the data is still missing, or to hide the layouts while the data is loading and only show them once the data is available.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can you please look at the Video I linked in my Question. Maybe it's another problem. (I am using the FirebaseOfflineTool)